# What does "jukai" mean?

Tags: words

Does anyone know what "jukai" means? Does it exist in the Japanese language? Some said it means 'birth or emergence'. Some said it is not "jukai" but maybe "jetai" 'fertilization, conception (breeding)'.

Comment: Please use a dictionary for the questions like this.

Comment: Thanks! Could you direct me to an online dictionary please.

Comment: http://www.alc.co.jp/ (extensive, but doesn't accept romaji and has no pronunciation guides)

http://tangorin.com/ and http://jisho.org/ (smaller, but friendlier to foreigners)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only find 3 occurrences of `じゅかい` in my 大辞泉 (none of them dealing with birth):

- 受戒　→　accepting/receiving Buddhist precepts
- 授戒　→　giving/conferring Buddhist precepts to followers
- 樹海　→　a "sea of trees"; "broad expanse of dense woodland"

`Jetai` is not a Japanese word.

Comment: Actually, you're right! the third meaning is the one I was looking for! Expense of dense wood land!
Thanks a lot man!